# Concatenate two different JSON objects from an API call in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, rest

I am working on a currency conversion project trying to get my code to display results from a JSON response on my website and I am not able to do it yet.
The code below,

```
  .then((response) => {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((jsonResponse) => {
      let objData = {
        amount: '',
        from: '',
        to: '',
        result: '',
      };
      window.console.log('jsonresponse ==>' + JSON.stringify(jsonResponse));
      let exchangeData = jsonResponse['query'];
      window.console.log('exchangeData==> ' + JSON.stringify(exchangeData))
      objData.amount = exchangeData['amount'];
      objData.from = exchangeData['from'];
      objData.to = exchangeData['to'];
      objData.result = exchangeData['result'];
      this.conversionData = objData;
      window.console.log('objData=' + JSON.stringify(objData));

    }).catch(error => {
      window.console.log('callout error ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    })

  }

}
```

returns only 'amount', 'from' and 'to' and not 'result'.
How can I get it to return the result of the conversion.
This is the sample JSON

```
{   "info": { "quote": 0.975625, "timestamp": 1669042263 }, 
    "query": { "amount": 5, "from": "USD", "to": "EUR" }, 
    "result": 4.878125, 
    "success": true 
}
```

For now, my code only returns

```
"query": {
    "amount": 5,
    "from": "USD",
    "to": "EUR"
```

How can I get it to return

```
"query": {
    "amount": 5,
    "from": "USD",
    "to": "EUR"
 "result": 4.878125
```

I have tried the below and it did not work.

```
const obj1={"query":[ { "amount":"", "from": "", "to": "" }, ] }; 
const obj2={"result":{}, }; 
const response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1)); 
response.query.push(...obj2.result); console.log(response);
```

Comment: `result` is not in `exchangeData`, it should be `jsonResponse.result`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are asking result from the wrong place

```
objData.result = exchangeData['result'];
```

where

```
let exchangeData = jsonResponse['query'];
```

But  `jsonResponse['query']` does not contain result.

You should do

```
objData.result = jsonResponse['result'];
```

instead.